# Why is the vieweing field a frustum instead of a pyramid?

Tags: 3d, culling, frustum, view, frustum-culling

[image]

In 3D games, why would the viewing field be a frustum? Why not a pyramid?

You would still have to do culling to figure out what's in the field, and to me it seems a pyramid field is **no harder to do culling math** than a frustum field.

Is it just because of worries that a small object may wander directly in front of the camera, blocking the entire view? To me that seems **more a problem of game design and good auto-camera control**, rather than a choice of viewing field geometry. (Also, that worry can still exist with a frustum field, if the near plane is relatively close to camera.)

Btw, I'm under the impression that the vast majority of games use a frustum, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you've read past Q&A about the near plane, covering [the kinds of errors we get when trying to project vertices with a near plane too close to the camera](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/141905/39518), and [the fundamental limitations of clipping math that demand we clip against a plane](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/191775/39518)?

Comment: @DMGregory I saw both of them but did not fully read them until now. I did not get much out of them. However, one had a link to a "Love your Z-Buffer" article, and that was an insanely helpful article. I don't know if I can translate that to an answer in my own words, though, not quit yet, but something to do with precision at near ranges.

Comment: I don't know if the *question* is a duplicate, but the answer to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/194408/46779 also applies here: it's a frustum because you can't linearly warp a pyramid into a cube.

Comment: @Mark But then, why do we have to insist on linear warps? What's the fundamental reason why the GPU can't perform some nonlinear operation on the depth value? I mean, it's *convenient* that everything is linear and therefore everything is a matrix, but why does it *have* to be?

Comment: @user253751, the warp to turn a pyramid into a cube involves division by zero.  More generally, computing linear functions like addition and multiplication is much faster than computing nonlinear functions, and in many cases, nonlinear functions aren't computable.